# Windows Server 2008 Mass Ownership Reassignment

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, permissions

A directory with a multitude of subdirectories at a client's office need to have ownership changed to a single Administrator account. Instead of changing the security settings for each and every subdirectory within the one folder (which could take me weeks), is it possible to perform a mass ownership reassignment to each and every subdirectory within one single directory?

Comment: don't rtfw much do we?

Comment: Not familiar with that acronym, so probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into icacls with the /t and /c switches.